# Tensorflow distributed asynchronous training example with high level api Experiment and Estimator

Tags: asynchronous, tensorflow, distributed

Is there any example about **tensorflow** distributed **asynchronous** training implemented with high level api [Experiment](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) and [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator)?

I can find the official **synchronous** example implemented with [Experiment](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) and [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator): [cifar10_estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10_estimator)

Also I can find an official **asynchronous** example with **tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession**: [tensorflow distributed asynchronous training code template](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed)

But there's no good example about asynchronous training implemented with Experiment and Estimator.

Can anyone show a complete example or teach me how to write one?

Comment: cifar10_estimator example is actually asynchronous by defaut, you need to add 'sync' flag to make is synchronous

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov thanks for your reply. I found a little difference between the two asynchronous examples. The cifar10_estimator asynchronous example uses only one input_fn, which generates train samples with 4 * batch_size, while [the official asynchronous example with MonitoredTrainingSession](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) uses 4 input_fns, each replica gets its own input_fn, if we have a parallelization on 4 GPUs. So the official asynchronous example is always faster than cifar10_estimator asynchronous example, it does not have a synchronization or block on the input_fn.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Not sure whether I understand it correctly. Pls correct me if my point is wrong.